# Has Facebook's API changed recently?

Tags: php, facebook

I built a project last year that had some basic facebook features, such as fetching a user's name, email, and importing his friends. That project is still working, however the client contacted me to tell me that Facebook's API has changed and I need to update the code before the legacy support goes away.

I can't find any mention of such changes, can someone point me to see what has changed and how I can update the code?

Comment: If you used `offline_access`, you need to change that, it's being deprecated. There were changes, but if it's working, then no need to touch anything (I guess).

Comment: @webarto do you know of a URL where I can see all the changes? Post it as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: knock yourself out http://developers.facebook.com/docs/changelog/ :)

Comment: "Last year" isn't even "recently" in Facebook time. Hell, a month ago is ancient news for Facebook's API.

Comment: @ceejayoz, this! We can only hope that not so long ago introduced [Breaking Change Policy](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/change-policy/) will allow us to be prepared on time...

Answer (score 2):

You may follow next topics to get informed about API and functionality changes:

- [Change Log](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/changelog/)
- [Developer Roadmap](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/)
- [Completed Changes](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/)